# Docker-compose: merge/combine two containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker environment for my project. Let me explain.

I have a project called `my-project` which produces a war `my-project.war`. I created a Docker image called `my-project:latest` which contains the `my-project.war` in the `/my-project` directory. That was easy.

Now I want to combine the Docker images `my-project:latest` and `tomcat:latest` (which is the official Docker image for Tomcat) in `docker-compose.yml`. I started with this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-project:
    image: my-project:latest
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

But how can I now copy the file `/my-project/my-project.war` from the `my-project` container to the `webapps/` directory in the `tomcat` container? Is this possible in docker-compose or should I start from a new `Dockerfile`?

In other words, I am having troubles *combining* these two containers.

Comment: You have to make this deployment in your `tomcat:latest` via `Dockerfile` before you use the `docker-compose`. So, when you compose the container everything will be there already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that in docker-compose. You can however use a very nice feature in docker called [MultiStage Build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/)

Basically, create a new Dockerfile to combine the images into one:

```
FROM my-project:latest as project

FROM tomcat:latest
COPY --from=project /my-project/my-project.war /webapps
```

Once you build this image using `docker build -t app .` you will have a tomcat image that contains you war at `/webapps'.

In the docker-compose just use this image:

```
version: "3"
services:
  application:
    image: app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever way. This makes me think though: wasn't it easier if the Docker image `my-project` already derived from `tomcat:latest` instead of `scratch` and I copy the `my-project.war` to `/webapps` (instead of `/my-project` as I originally did)? This way, I only have to create one Docker image instead of two. Is this a smart idea?

Comment: Yes definitely do that.

Comment: I will experiment and let you know tomorrow. I will also accept the answer then.