# How to call Ansible through Rundeck using docker container?

Tags: docker, ansible, rundeck

I am trying to call Ansible through Rundeck. I have created the dockercompose file like this:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  Rundeck:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    image: 'jordan/rundeck'
    ports:
      - '4440:4440/tcp'
    volumes:
     - /root/ansibledemo:/data

  ansible:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    image: 'ansible/ansible:default'
    volumes:
     - /root/ansibledemo:/data1
```

With this file I am able to create the 2 services, one is for Rundeck and the other is for Ansible. But my question is: when I try to run the job from Rundeck web interface I am facing the following issue:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ansible-playbook: not found
13:10:10            Result: 127
13:10:10            Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 127
13:10:10            Execution failed: 1 in project demo: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [localhost: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 127 + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(step:1, node:localhost)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=127}}}, ContextView(node:localhost)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=127}}}}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {localhost=[NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 127 + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(step:1, node:localhost)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=127}}}, ContextView(node:localhost)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=127}}}}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
```

How to call Ansible through Rundeck using docker container?

Answer (score 1):

Default Rundeck Docker image doesn't contain Ansible, you need that Ansible coexists in the same container that Rundeck, you have three options:

1) Create your own container with Rundeck and Ansible. 
2) If you want, use this image, works great: https://hub.docker.com/r/batix/rundeck-ansible/ 
3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47462089/10426011 (more complicated I think)